# Room specific ban in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat-ban

Sometimes it does not make sense to ban a user from all chatrooms. As we all know, C++, Java & PHP developers 'love' each other very much (yes I know many people can develop in all three languages, but more often than not, people identify themselves with only one main language).

Occasionally one person can get banned from one room for asking irrelevant questions, but the user can be very knowledgeable in another language/room. Can chat implement different levels of bans? One being the current chat wide, and one being room specific.

Comment: Just don't get banned from a chatroom. If you're banned from one, what guarantee do I have you won't cause similar trouble in another room?

Comment: Because I might own the other room.

Comment: You're still here?

Comment: I'd say as a room owner you might want to hold yourself to an even higher standard.

Answer (score 9):

If the suspension is well deserved, I think it is appropriate that you get suspended from all rooms. Additionally, some users might be tempted to some non-constructive behaviour in other chat rooms in response to a single-room suspension.

Comment: What about the room the user actually owns?

Comment: Anybody can become a room owner, that is not something that deserves any special protection in my opinion.